# React-Native wait for AsyncStorage.getItem()

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am facing problem exactly like what is mentioned in the link below:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8589

Wish to load from AsyncStorage and set a few global variables. Because the rest of the pages depending on those variables.

If I use **async await** or **then()** I still can't stop the rest of the pages from rendering before the **global** variables are set.

I tried to make every component **async**, but unfortunately I can't get it working as well.

Mainly because of this line:

```
const _App = (props) => {
  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
        <App />
    </I18nextProvider>);
}

// registerComponent() can't accept anything that is Async
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => _App);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
const _App = (props) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

  useEffect(()=>{

    const functionName = async () => {
      await registerComponent()
      setLoaded(true)
    }

    functionName()
  },[])

  if(!loaded) return <View><Text>Some Fancy loading stuff here</Text></View>

    return (
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
          <App />
      </I18nextProvider>);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, seems like forbidding all blocking calls is the main policy of android / ios. Adding a splash screen is the only option.